Android - Play pre launch report complains entire screen is missing content description
I'm writing a compose app using Material 3 implemented as a single activity inheriting from ComponentActivity.
setContent {
    MyTheme {
        Scaffold(...)

The pre launch report from Google Play draws a dashed red line around the entire screen and complains it is lacking an "item label".
I have tried adding a content description modifier to everything I can think of, but it doesn't help.
Am I missing something obvious? Is there a resource somewhere explaining how to read element paths like this android:id/content/C0[1]/B[1]? I have no idea what C and B means.
